# Неполадки с ScheduledExecutorService

Tags: java

Здравствуй, ХэшКод!

Возникла небольшая проблемка, как было порекомендовано мне в прошлой теме ([моделируем время в программе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/351087/java-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8F-%D0%B2-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B5) )

Я сделал небольшую штукенцию...Но она отказывается хорошо работать, смотрите, есть такой код:

```
if(s == 1){
  t = 2;
  Time();
}else{
  t = t*2;
  Time();
}

static void Time() {
    ScheduledExecutorService ses = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
        Runnable pinger = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                System.out.println("PING!" + " " + t);
        }
    };
  ses.scheduleAtFixedRate(pinger, t, t, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
}
```

Видно, что временем рулит переменная - t(static int t;) , также видно что в конструкции else время увеличивается на два раза,но! ( я проверил переменная t передается в метод Time()) Кажется как будто время как было 2, так и осталось, несмотря на то, что я увеличивал переменную хоть в тысячу раз..

out:

PING! 2

PING! 2

PING! 4 - промежуток между этим пингом

PING! 4 - и этим тоже равен двум

**UPD**

Вот код:  http://pastebin.com/BVCFZXdY

Попробуйте ввести: сначала вводим input, потом два раза букву a английскую, например..

Comment: Вы запускаемый код покажите, в котором есть все детали, связанные с вашей проблемой. А то остается только гадать, что там у вас происходит.

Answer (score 1):

> я проверил переменная t передается в метод Time()

Переменная у вас статичная. Вы ее не контролируете, соответственно ждите сюрпризов.

```
f(s == 1){
  t = 2;
  Time(t);
}else{
  t = t*2;
  Time(t);
}
static ScheduledExecutorService ses = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);    
static void Time(final int time) {
        Runnable pinger = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                System.out.println("PING!" + " " + time);
        }
    };
  ses.scheduleAtFixedRate(pinger, time, time, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
}
```

Так должно заработать.

Comment: Что то никак,как было так и есть...